# Insert Performance Benchmarks

Tags: postgresql

It would be extremely useful to have some idea of expected performance benchmarks for inserts in a postgresql database.  Typically the type of answers one would get on this are vague, and in many ways rightly so.  For example, answers could range from every database is different, to it depends on the number of indexes/columns, to hardware makes a big difference, to db tuning makes a big difference etc.  **MY goal** is to know the general guidelines of insert performance, roughly at an equivalent level as when an experienced SQL Developer's intuition says "this seems slow, I should try to optimize this".

Let me illustrate, someone could ask how much does it cost to buy a house?  We answer, expensive!  And there are many factors that go into the price such as size of the house and location in the country.  BUT, to the person asking the question, they might think $20,000 is a lot of money so houses must cost about that much.  Saying it's expensive and there are a lot of variables obviously doesn't help the person asking the question much.  It would be MUCH more helpful for someone to say, in general the "normal" cost of houses ranges from $100K-$1M, the average middle-class family can afford a house between $200K and $500K, and a normal cost per square foot is $100/square foot.

All that to say I'm looking for ballpark performance benchmarks on inserts for the following factors

1. Inserting 1000, 10000, 100000 rows into average table size of 15 columns.
2. Rough effect of every additional 5 columns added to the table
3. Rough effect of each index on the table
4. Effect of special types of indexes
5. Any other ideas that people have

I'm fine with gut feel answers on these if you are an experienced postgresql performance tuner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a meaningful figure here for the list of conditions you specified, because you do not even list the types of conditions that would have a profound effect on the speed of the `INSERT` command:

- Hardware capabilities:

  - CPU speed + number of cores
  - storage speed
  - memory speed and size
- Cluster architecture, in case the batch is huge and can cross over
- Execution scenario:

  - text batch, with pre-generated inserts one-by-one
  - direct stream-based insert
  - insert via a specific driver, like an ORM

In addition, the insert speed can be:

- maintained (consistent or average) speed
- single-operation speed, i.e. for a single batch execution

You can always find a combination of such criteria so bad you would be struggling to do 100 inserts a second, and on the other side it is possible to go over 1m of inserts in a properly set up environment and execution plan.

So you will find the speed of your implementation somewhere in between, but given the known conditions, the speed will be 42 :)